# What are the theological implications of distributing Communion under one kind only?

Tags: catholicism, communion, covid-19

When I attended my first Catholic mass some time in November, I noticed that the priest only distributed the Holy Eucharist under the [species](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36585) of bread, not wine. Upon further research, I learned this was due to COVID restrictions. Which brings up a serious question: What are the theological implications of such a change, especially in relation to Christ commanding to consume the Eucharist under the species of both the bread and wine during Mass?

Comment: Did the priest only consecrate bread (no wine at all) or did he consecrate wine but did drink it alone and the faithfull did only get the Lords body?

Comment: This is a very vague question. What do you mean by 'theological implications'?

Comment: I think a nice compromise would be for everyone to bring their own bottle, each put it on the altar, and then the priest consecrate all the bottles. Would this be a theological 'implication'?

Comment: I should clarify I don't like the accidents of the wine, not the essence, of course!

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Perhaps you should re-read your comments.  You are not a troll.

Comment: @MikeBorden I re-read them and laughed. :) But using one's own bottle of wine is a serious suggestion. Why not? Jesus himself made some of the finest wine (perhaps the finest wine?). Why don't we up our game?

Comment: I really don’t understand how this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @LukeHill I agree.

Comment: the title of the other question doesn't seem like a duplicate, but the gist of the question "why does only the priest receive Communion under both kinds" is the same question. the answer "Why", should encompass the theological considerations.  I can clarify that other question and open a bounty on it if you want.

Comment: Also, there is another question that is still opened which is almost a verbatim dupe https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24905/what-is-the-theological-justification-for-only-the-priest-drinking-the-wine-in-a?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @PeterTurner yea then my question is defo a dupe. Sorry, it didn't pop up on similar questions, probably due to my wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thinking behind it was developed by Thomas Aquinas who taught what is called, “[Concomitance](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/4080.htm).” Essentially, it means that “nothing is lost by the body being received by the people without the blood.”

Serving communion in only one form (i.e. the bread/body) is also practiced in Lutheran & Episcopal churches in relationship to those struggling with alcoholism, fear of virus transmission, etc.

Comment: It is also very common as a practice for daily mass in our diocese: only the body is served to the faithful. The body and blood on Sunday Mass.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Is "to serve Communion" standard terminology? I thought one said "to distribute Communion". {"To serve" sounds more like what restaurants do; and in a theological context, "to serve" sounds like service (worship we give to God) or altar server.}

Comment: @Geremia in the Lutheran tradition the Divine service is mostly what God does for us. Servers mirror that theology in channeling God’s sacramental gifts.

Comment: @geremia I'll check with our Deacon, there may be a distinction there which I have not quite grasped. Distribute may be the more grammatically accurate term. EDIT:  OK, I checked the USCCB, and it is indeed *distribute* -- *Bishops, priests and deacons distribute Holy Communion in virtue of their office as ordinary ministers of the Body and Blood of the Lord* Thank you for the correction.